# How to capture the file name from the server dynamically when some one uploads it

Tags: java, file, jsp, upload

Below is the code to read the file from the server. I Want to read & convert the file dynamically (not hard coded )into different file format(CSV). Could anyone please guide me to capture the uploaded file name dynamically.

```
try
    {

        //creating File instance to reference text file in Java

        String str1=null;
        String str2=null;
        String str3=null;
        int cnt=0,len1=0,len2=0;


        File text = new File("C:\\Petty Ascii Detail.txt");

        //Creating Scanner instnace to read File in Java

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(text);


        File file = new File("C:\\Test\\Write1.txt");

       //if file doesnt exists, then create it
      if (!file.exists()) 
      {
        file.createNewFile();
      }

       //Reading each line of file using Scanner class

       int lineNumber = 1;
       while(scnr.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = scnr.nextLine();
            cnt=line.length(); 

            for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            {

                if (Character.isDigit(line.charAt(i)))
                    str1=line;
                else
                    str2=line;
            }

            len1=str1.length();
            len2=str2.length();

            if(len1!=len2)
            {
                str3=str1+str2;

                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(),true);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

                bw.write(str3);
                bw.newLine();

                System.out.println("Done");

                bw.close();

            }

                lineNumber++;
        }      



    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any suggestions are really appreciated.

Thanks,
Balaji

Comment: How are people uploading files? How do you receive them?

Comment: See the documentation/examples at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/